# How to pull a random record using Django's ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model that represents paintings I present on my site. On the main webpage I'd like to show some of them: newest, one that was not visited for most time, most popular one and a random one.

I'm using Django 1.0.2.

While first 3 of them are easy to pull using django models, last one (random) causes me some trouble. I can ofc code it in my view, to something like this:

```
number_of_records = models.Painting.objects.count()
random_index = int(random.random()*number_of_records)+1
random_paint = models.Painting.get(pk = random_index)
```

It doesn't look like something I'd like to have in my view tho - this is entirely part of database abstraction and should be in the model. Also, here I need to take care of removed records (then number of all records won't cover me all the possible key values) and probably lots of other things.

Any other options how I can do it, preferably somehow inside the model abstraction?

Comment: How you display things and which things you display is part of the "View" level or business logic that should go in the "Controller" level of MVC, in my opinion.

Comment: In Django the controller is the view. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names

Comment: There should be a built-in function for this - one that does not use `order_by('?')`

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Using `order_by('?')` will kill the db server on the second day in production. A better way is something like what is described in [Getting a random row from a relational database](http://web.archive.org/web/20110802060451/http://bolddream.com/2010/01/22/getting-a-random-row-from-a-relational-database/).

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Count
from random import randint

class PaintingManager(models.Manager):
    def random(self):
        count = self.aggregate(count=Count('id'))['count']
        random_index = randint(0, count - 1)
        return self.all()[random_index]
```

Comment: What are the benefits of `model.objects.aggregate(count=Count('id'))['count']` over `model.objects.all().count()`

Comment: While much better than the accepted answer, note that this approach makes two SQL queries. If the count changes in between, it might be possible to get an out of bounds error.

Comment: Maybe annotate random(self) should be annotated with "@transaction.atomic" to avoid changing-count issues? https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: @JohanWalles If you use transactions, you defeat the very purpose of this technique in terms of performance (vs the `order_by('?')`).

Comment: Is there a way to get two random rows, without adding a query? Something like this: `return self.all().filter(rownumber__in[random_index, random_index2])`

Comment: How can I call it in a view?

Comment: This is a wrong solution. It will not work if your ids do not start from 0. And also when ids are not contiguous. Say, the first record starts from 500 and the last one is 599 (assuming contiguity). Then the count would 54950. Surely list[54950] does not exist because your queryst's length is 100. It will throw index out of bound exception. I do not know why so many people upvoted this and this was marked as accepted answer.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy Did you do the math?

Comment: @sajid: Why, exactly, are you asking me? It is quite easy to see the sum total of my contributions to this question: editing a link to point to an archive after it rotted. I haven't even voted on any of the answers. But I do find it amusing that this answer and the one you claim to be much better both use `.all()[randint(0, count - 1)]` in effect. Maybe you should focus on identifying what part of the answer is wrong or weak, rather than redefining "off-by-one-error" for us and yelling at the foolish voters. (Maybe it's that it's not using `.objects`?)

Comment: This works fine regardless of id distribution (contiguous, non-contiguous, starting at 0 or otherwise). The only valid objection is @NeloMitranim's.

Comment: @NeloMitranim Do you see a way around the 2 query problem? The only thing I could think of would be pulling the contents of the entire table at once in one go and then working on that list in the application, which I'm not sure if that's actually faster for larger tables. Like, we often say that querying the database is slow, but I can't imagine querying the entire table and turning 10k+ entries into python objects is faster when you only need 1.

Comment: @PhilippDoerner Something like this should work, but I have no idea about the idiomatic way of doing this in Django:

`select * from some_table limit 1 offset trunc(random() * (select count(*) from some_table));`

Comment: @NeloMitranim Thanks! This is the type of thing that Django provides you the ability to run raw queries for, as I doubt Django's ORM covers these types of SQL abilities. For future onlookers not aware of this (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries): You could do `models.Painting.objects.raw("<SQL QUERY ABOVE>")`.

Answer (score 306):

Simply use:

```
MyModel.objects.order_by('?').first()
```

It is documented in [QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by).

Comment: Please note that this approach can be very slow, as documented :)

Comment: "may be expensive and slow, depending on the database backend you're using." - any experience on diffrent DB backends? (sqlite/mysql/postgres)?

Comment: I haven't tested it, so this is pure speculation: why should it be slower than retrieving all items and performing randomization in  Python?

Comment: Think this approach _can_ be slow, but doesn't have to. If DB backend doesn't support it this will be done in Python. If it does, the DB returns random record

Comment: i read that it's slow in mysql, as mysql has incredibly inefficient random ordering.

Comment: If the backend doesn't support random ordering it makes sense for this to be slow as the ORM has to retrieve all records, shuffle them (likely O(n)) and then take the first one.

Comment: Why not just `random.choice(Model.objects.all())`?

Comment: @Jamey That's prefered when the number of records is small and hot in the database heap.

Comment: Here is an explanation why you should not use random sort http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731346/how-to-get-two-random-records-with-django/6405601#6405601

Comment: @kender - With Postgres table of 350,000 rows: cost ~25,000, response time = 67ms.

Performance isn't bad with smaller datasets. Once you get in the millions of rows, then Emil's solution below is much better.

Comment: I was amazed how slow this was (as warned by @NicDumZ ).  Similar to @Jamey, I pulled a list of ids of all available objects up front.  Then did the `np.random.choice(list_of_ids)`, and then `Model.objects.get(id=id)` each time I needed another.

Comment: @Jamey's approach is much better for picking a random but .order_by('?') is useful for random ordering.

Comment: Jamey's suggestion hauls the entire table (all columns) into Python to perform randomization there. You need a very small table for this to be better than two queries to get the count first and then select one random row using `OFFSET`and `LIMIT`.

Comment: This is great but not too related to the question as if I need 50 random samples, so I should have 50 columns to may have a probability of distinct results.

Answer (score 25):

The solutions with order_by('?')[:N] are extremely slow even for medium-sized tables if you use MySQL (don't know about other databases).

`order_by('?')[:N]` will be translated to `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT N` query.

It means that for every row in table the RAND() function will be executed, then the whole table will be sorted according to value of this function and then first N records will be returned. If your tables are small, this is fine. But in most cases this is a very slow query.

I wrote simple function that works even if id's have holes (some rows where deleted):

```
def get_random_item(model, max_id=None):
    if max_id is None:
        max_id = model.objects.aggregate(Max('id')).values()[0]
    min_id = math.ceil(max_id*random.random())
    return model.objects.filter(id__gte=min_id)[0]
```

It is faster than order_by('?') in almost all cases.

Comment: Also, sadly, it's far from random. If you have a record with id 1 and another with id 100, then it'll return the second one 99% of the time.

Answer (score 25):

**Here's a simple solution:**

```
from random import randint

count = Model.objects.count()
random_object = Model.objects.all()[randint(0, count - 1)] #single random object
```

Comment: This assumes your PKs are sequential with no gaps

Comment: @LukeCousins I use UUIDs for my PKs and this solution works for me.

Comment: @LukeCousins I know this response is a bit old.. but the reason this works even if there are PKs with gaps is because you aren't getting a random object based on PK but on a query set index. A PK list can be [45, 50, 90] or even a list of UUID's and it will still work cause you are getting a count of the resulting list and then choosing an index from that count.

Answer (score 11):

You could create a [manager](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) on your model to do this sort of thing.  To first understand what a manager is, the `Painting.objects` method is a manager that contains `all()`, `filter()`, `get()`, etc.  Creating your own manager allows you to pre-filter results and have all these same methods, as well as your own custom methods, work on the results.

**EDIT**: I modified my code to reflect the `order_by['?']` method.  Note that the manager returns an unlimited number of random models.  Because of this I've included a bit of usage code to show how to get just a single model.

```
from django.db import models

class RandomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(RandomManager, self).get_query_set().order_by('?')

class Painting(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    randoms = RandomManager() # The random-specific manager.
```

**Usage**

```
random_painting = Painting.randoms.all()[0]
```

Lastly, you can have many managers on your models, so feel free to create a `LeastViewsManager()` or `MostPopularManager()`.

Comment: Using get() would only work if your pks are consecutive, ie you never delete any items. Otherwise you are likely to try and get a pk that doesn't exist. Using .all()[random_index] doesn't suffer from this problem and isn't any less efficient.

Comment: I understood that which is why my example simply replicates the question's code with a manager.  It will still be up to the OP to work out his bounds checking.

Comment: instead of using .get(id=random_index) wouldnt it be better to use .filter(id__gte=random_index)[0:1] ? First, it helps solving the problem with non-consecutive pks. Second, get_query_set should return... a QuerySet. And in your example, it does not.

Comment: I wouldn't create a new manager just to house one method. I'd add "get_random" to the default manager so that you wouldn't have to go through the all()[0] hoop everytime you need the random image. Furthermore, if author were a ForeignKey to a User model, you could say user.painting_set.get_random().

Comment: I typically create a new manager when I want a blanket action, like getting a list of random records.  I'd create a method on the default manager if i were doing a more specific task with the records i already had.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers are either potentially slow (using `order_by('?')`) or use more than one SQL query. Here's a sample solution with no ordering and just one query (assuming Postgres):

```py
random_instance_or_none = Model.objects.raw('''
    select * from {0} limit 1
    offset floor(random() * (select count(*) from {0}))
'''.format(Model._meta.db_table)).first()
```

Be aware that this will raise an index error if the table is empty. Write yourself a model-agnostic helper function to check for that.

Comment: A nice proof of concept, but this is two queries as well inside the database, what you save is one roundtrip to the database. You'd have to execute this a great many times to make writing and maintaining a raw query worth it. And if you want to guard against empty tables, you might just as well run a `count()` in advance and dispense with the raw query.

Answer (score 4):

Just a simple idea how I do it:

```
def _get_random_service(self, professional):
    services = Service.objects.filter(professional=professional)
    i = randint(0, services.count()-1)
    return services[i]
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi I needed to select a random record from a queryset who's length I also needed to report (ie web page produced described item and said  records left)

```
q = Entity.objects.filter(attribute_value='this or that')
item_count = q.count()
random_item = q[random.randomint(1,item_count+1)]
```

took half as long(0.7s vs 1.7s) as:

```
item_count = q.count()
random_item = random.choice(q)
```

I'm guessing it avoids pulling down the whole query before selecting the random entry and made my system responsive enough for a page that is accessed repeatedly for a repetitive task where users want to see the item_count count down.

Answer (score 3):

Randomization in DB feels nasty and better in python. But at the same time, it's not a good idea to bring all the data from DB to python memory just to ignore most of the results (especially in the production environment). we might need some sort of filtering also.

1. So Basically we have data at DB,
2. we wanna use the rand function of python
3. and afterwords bring up the whole required data from DB.

Basically using 2 queries will be much less expensive than picking random in DB CPU (computing in DB) or loading whole data (heavy Network Utilization). Solutions explained must need a scalable nature trying to plan here won't work for a production environment espicially with filters, soft/hard deletes, or even with an is_public flag. because probably random id we generated might be deleted from the database or will be cut down in filters. Its a bad practice to assume max_id(records) == count(records).

(Ofcouce, If you do'not delete a percentage of data which is comparable to query uses, or if you dont wanna use any kond of filters, and if you are confident, random id which you can proceed with a random )

if you want only one items.
Refer ( @Valter Silva )

```
import random

mgr = models.Painting.objects
qs = mgr.filter(...)
random_id = random.choice(1, qs.count())-1        # <--- [ First Query Hit ]

random_paint = qs[random_id] ## <-- [ Second Query Hit ]
```

if you want 'n' items.

```
import random

req_no_of_random_items = 8        ## i need 8 random items.
qs = models.Painting.objects.filter(...)

## if u prefer to use random values often, you can keep this in cache. 
possible_ids = list(qs.values_list('id', flat=True))        # <--- [ First Query Hit ]

possible_ids = random.choices(possible_ids, k=8)
random_paint = qs.filter(pk__in=possible_ids) ## in a generic case to get 'n' items.
```

or if you want to have a more optimized code for production, use a cachefunction to get ids of products:

```
from django.core.cache import cache

def id_set_cache(qs):
    key = "some_random_key_for_cache"
    id_set =  cache.get(key)
    if id_set is None:
        id_set = list(qs.values_list('id', flat=True)
        cache.set(key, id_set)
    retrun id_set
```

Comment: When you have millions of rows this will kill the memory, even if you are only selecting the ID.

Answer (score 2):

Just to note a (fairly common) special case, if there is a indexed auto-increment column in the table with no deletes, the optimum way to do a random select is a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = RAND() LIMIT 1
```

that assumes such a column named id for table. In django you can do this by:

```
Painting.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM appname_painting WHERE id = RAND() LIMIT 1')
```

in which you must replace appname with your application name.

In General, with an id column, the order_by('?') can be done much faster with:

```
Paiting.objects.raw(
        'SELECT * FROM auth_user WHERE id>=RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM auth_user) LIMIT %d' 
    % needed_count)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Method for auto-incrementing primary key with no deletes

If you have a table where the primary key is a sequential integer with no gaps, then the following method should work:

```
import random
max_id = MyModel.objects.last().id
random_id = random.randint(0, max_id)
random_obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=random_id)
```

This method is much more efficient than other methods here that iterate through all rows of the table. While it does require two database queries, both are trivial. Furthermore, it's simple and doesn't require defining any extra classes. However, it's applicability is limited to tables with an auto-incrementing primary key where rows have never deleted, such that there are no gaps in the sequence of ids.

In the case where rows have been deleted such that are gaps, this method could still work if it is retried until an existing primary key is randomly selected.

### References

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10836811/4651668
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2118712/4651668
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39751708/4651668
- https://github.com/greenelab/hetmech-backend/pull/48

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the different answers to this question, please remember the right solution depends on your use case.

### Method 1 (big DB, no deletions, pk starts from 1)

If the records on your database **have sequential primary keys** with no gaps (if you **never delete objects** from your database):

Select one random object:

```py
import random

# Get the biggest primary key
# (generally ):
pk_max= MyModel.objects.all().aggregate(pk_max=Max("pk"))['pk_max']

# Pick a random primary key:
random_pk = random.randint(1, pk_max)

# Get that object:
random_object = MyModel.objects.get(pk=random_pk )
```

Select n random objects:

```py
import random
n = 5

pk_max= MyModel.objects.all().aggregate(pk_max=Max("pk"))['pk_max']

random_pk_list = random.sample(range(1,pk_max+1), n)

random_objects = MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=random_pk_list)
# Note: this one returns a QuerySet
```

***Problem:*** Will start crying if you ever have a gap in your primary key column. It makes a huge assumption about the future of your database for probably a very critical operation.

### Method 2 (small DB, no deletions, pk starts from 1)

(Note: both A and B are not efficient at all. Only use these if you have to. If your DB table is small enough to do this, maybe you don't even need a table for this and can use something like enums, etc.)

##### A. By randomly **order**ing the ENTIRE table with SQL:

```py
# Get one random object:
random_object = MyModel.objects.order_by('?').first()

# Get n Random objects:
random_objects = MyModel.objects.order_by('?')[:n]
```

***Problem:*** It uses SQL's `ORDER BY RAND()`, which may go on your criminal record as a misdemeanor in certain countries in the near future. Also there is a very good chance that it will generate a new temporary table and random numbers for every single record before ordering them based on these random numbers. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731346/how-to-get-two-random-records-with-django/6405601) for a great technical explanation.

##### B. By loading ALL the objects from the table first:

```py
import random
# Don't do this!
every_single_object_ever = MyModel.objects.all()

# Get one random object:
random_object = random.choice(every_single_object_ever)

# Get n Random objects:
random_objects = random.choices(every_single_object_ever, k=n)
```

***Problem:*** You are loading all the objects from your table as Django's MyModel instances to get a single(or several) record.
(Tbh 'every_single_object_ever is a queryset until you use it in the random.choice method')

You can improve this a little bit;

##### C. By loading ALL the ids from the table first:

Remember that this solution is still terrible, and now it uses two queries instead of one:

```py
import random

every_single_pk_ever = MyModel.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)

# Get one random object:
random_object = random.choice(every_single_pk_ever )

# Get n Random objects:
random_objects = random.choices(every_single_pk_ever , k=n)
```

***Problem:*** Loads every single pk in the table just to get some of them.

### Method 3 (big DB with deletions(or gaps), pk is an integer)

Method 1 assumes that you have sequential primary keys with no gaps. We can get around this using SQL's `OFFSET X LIMIT Y`. So instead of defining the primary keys, you will specify the index of the row.

This is almost identical to Emil Ivanov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2118712/2754871):

```py
# first query:
count = MyModel.objects.all().count()

# second query:
random_offset = random.randint(0,count-1)
MyModel.objects.all()[random_offset].get()
```

This works efficiently because Django uses python's slicing to modify the query's LIMIT and OFFSET values. [See the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) for more on this.
***Problem:*** Since this one uses two queries, total count of the records may change during this period, as Nelo Mitranim stated before. This may throw an exception. Notice how I used .get() at the end. This is to make sure the code throws a DoesNotExist exception if anything goes wrong. Without the .get(), it would throw an IndexError instead.

For multiple objects, you could do `MyModel.objects.all()[random_offset-n:random_offset]` but this would make your 'random' objects have sequential row numbers, which means it is more of a random slice from your database. For a list of completely random objects, you would need to get random.sample() between 1 and your count, and run the `MyModel.objects.all()[random_offset]` line in a for loop. Which gets quite painful if you need lets say 50 random objects. Which means:

#### We need another solution for gathering multiple random objects.

Let's say we need ***3*** random objects. What happens if I do this?

```py
pk_max= MyModel.objects.all().aggregate(pk_max=Max("pk"))['pk_max']

random_pk_list = random.sample(range(1,pk_max+1), 10)

random_objects = MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=random_pk_list)[:3]
```

It translates to this:

```
SELECT * FROM `myapp_mymodel` WHERE id IN (1, 3, 7, 8, 11, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29) LIMIT 3
```

I only need 3 objects. But I am giving it a list of 10 possible primary keys to choose from. This lowers my chances of hitting a gap and ending up with zero, one or two objects. Performance? Well, since your database engine stops looking for more records when it hits the LIMIT, generating random numbers at the beginning is the only performance sacrifice you are making. Which is not much. If you are positive that you have enough records, you can send a thousand possible primary keys instead:

```py
pk_max= MyModel.objects.all().aggregate(pk_max=Max("pk"))['pk_max']

random_pk_list = random.sample(range(1,pk_max+1), 1000)

random_objects = MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=random_pk_list)[:3]
```

### Method 4 (Database specific SQL queries, aka getting your hands dirty)

You can always execute raw queries with Django. This might be as simple as this for *some database engines*:

```py
random_object_list = MyModel.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_mymodel LIMIT 1 OFFSET TRUNCATE(RANDOM() * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myapp_mymodel))')
```

But most of them [require a constant](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) for the OFFSET. A working alternative for the Mysql can be found below(Note: this is an overkill). It locks the table. Sets a random offset based on the count of objects in our table to a variable, and executes the Select query with this random OFFSET value.

```py
from django.db import connection
with connection.cursor():
    cursor.execute('LOCK TABLE myapp_mymodel WRITE;')
    cursor.execute("SET @randomoffset=CAST(truncate((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
myapp_mymodel)*RAND(),0)+0 AS SIGNED);")
    cursor.execute("PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM myapp_mymodel LIMIT 1 OFFSET ?';")
    cursor.execute("EXECUTE STMT USING @randomoffset;")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.execute('UNLOCK TABLES;')

print(row)
```

You can still increase the performance. Two naive solutions I can think of are importing MySQLDb directly and executing above commands in a single cursor.execute() without the ugly table lock, or using ROWID(if supported) in a where clause instead of the OFFSET since high [OFFSETs can cause performance issues](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page).

### Final note:

Since it is easier to ask for forgiveness than permission, I'd say just go with method 3, and if you encounter an error, try it again. Do it in a while loop if you really need it, most of the time the query will only need to run once.

Answer (score 1):

This is Highly recomended <s>[Getting a random row from a relational database](http://bolddream.com/2010/01/22/getting-a-random-row-from-a-relational-database/)</s>

Because using django orm to do such a thing like that, will makes your db server angry specially if you have big data table :|

And the solution is provide a Model Manager and write the SQL query by hand ;)

**Update**:

Another solution which works on any database backend even non-rel ones without writing custom `ModelManager`. [Getting Random objects from a Queryset in Django](http://elpenia.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/getting-random-objects-from-a-queryset-in-django/)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the [same approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12583436/623735) that you'd use to sample any iterator, especially if you plan to sample multiple items to create a *sample set*. @MatijnPieters and @DzinX put a lot of thought into this:

```
def random_sampling(qs, N=1):
    """Sample any iterable (like a Django QuerySet) to retrieve N random elements

    Arguments:
      qs (iterable): Any iterable (like a Django QuerySet)
      N (int): Number of samples to retrieve at random from the iterable

    References:
      @DZinX:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12583436/623735
      @MartinPieters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12581484/623735
    """
    samples = []
    iterator = iter(qs)
    # Get the first `N` elements and put them in your results list to preallocate memory
    try:
        for _ in xrange(N):
            samples.append(iterator.next())
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError("N, the number of reuested samples, is larger than the length of the iterable.")
    random.shuffle(samples)  # Randomize your list of N objects
    # Now replace each element by a truly random sample
    for i, v in enumerate(qs, N):
        r = random.randint(0, i)
        if r < N:
            samples[r] = v  # at a decreasing rate, replace random items
    return samples
```

Comment: Matijn's and DxinX's solution is for data sets that provide no random access. For data sets that do (and SQL does with `OFFSET`), this is unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: @EndreBoth indeed. I just like the coding "efficiency" of using the same approach irrespective of the data source. Sometimes data sampling efficiency doesn't significantly affect the performance of a pipeline limited by other processes (whatever you're actually doing with the data, like ML training).

Answer (score 1):

One much easier approach to this involves simply filtering down to the recordset of interest and using `random.sample` to select as many as you want:

```
from myapp.models import MyModel
import random

my_queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(criteria=True)  # Returns a QuerySet
my_object = random.sample(my_queryset, 1)  # get a single random element from my_queryset
my_objects = random.sample(my_queryset, 5)  # get five random elements from my_queryset
```

Note that you should have some code in place to verify that `my_queryset` is not empty; `random.sample` returns `ValueError: sample larger than population` if the first argument contains too few elements.

Comment: Will this cause the whole query set to be retrieved?

Comment: @perrohunter It won't even work with `Queryset` (at least with Python 3.7 and Django 2.1); you have to convert it to a list first, which obviously retrieves the whole queryset.

Comment: @EndreBoth - this was written in 2016, when neither of those existed.

Comment: That's why I added the version info. But if it worked in 2016, it did so by pulling the entire queryset into a list, right?

Comment: @EndreBoth  Correct.

Answer (score 0):

Fast way via native SQL.

*tested with MySQL 8.x and Django 4.x*

I pull x random set of `record id's` from the table. With these id's I fetch the objects.

Example:

```
sql = "SELECT id FROM paintings ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"
list_of_ids = [p.id for p in Painting.objects.raw(sql)]
list_of_random_paintings = Painting.objects.filter(id__in=list_of_ids).all()
```

- via a optional WHERE you can change the scope of your query
- LIMIT is set to 1, if you need more records just change it

Quick benchmark, on:

- 107.251 records ~ 0.13 seconds
- 931.103 records ~ 0.8 seconds
- 8.044,965 records ~ 3.4 seconds

The bigger the table, the longer it takes. After all, using this depends on your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

This is in case you want to pull a LIST of random records. Pretty useful when you need to show only a random sample of a category.

```
import random

all_cat_objects = Model.objects.filter(category='category-name')
sample_objects = random.choices(all_cat_objects, k=10)  # only select 10
```

If the database is too big, get random datetime or pk field ranges, use WHERE clause and pick from them in python.

Answer (score -1):

I got very simple solution, make custom manager:

```
class RandomManager(models.Manager):
    def random(self):
        return random.choice(self.all())
```

and then add in model:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    objects = RandomManager()
```

Now, you can use it:

```
Example.objects.random()
```

Comment: from random import choice

Comment: Please, don't use this method, if you want speed. 
This solution is VERY slow. I've checked. It slower than `order_by('?').first()` more than 60 times.

Comment: @Alex78191 no, "?" is bad too, but my method is EXTRA slow.
I used top answer solution.