# How to select 30 unique random values from database(MySQL) with django?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, django-database

I've read this question: [In Django, how do I select 100 random records from the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506678/in-django-how-do-i-select-100-random-records-from-the-database)
And tried to use `Content.objects.all().order_by('?')[:30]`, but this will produce some duplicate items. So how could I select 30 **unique** random values from database?

Comment: For millions of items: Can you modify your models? Do you need a different order **each time**? You can create an `int` index in your model and assign `randint(MAXINT)` to it. Then `order_by('randindex')`. Resetting the order is `O(n)` but doable (every hour/day for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a manageable number of entries in the database (ie not thousands), this will work, and even though it hits the db twice it will probably be much more efficient than `order_by('?')`.

```
import random
content_pks = Content.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)
selected_pks = random.sample(content_pks, 30)
content_objects = Content.objects.filter(pk__in=selected_pks)
```

Comment: Surely selecting thousands of ids should not be a problem. It's only a single column!

Comment: Yes, probably should have said "millions".

Comment: I tried this and found a problem of it. When you use `Content.objects.filter(pk__in=selected_pks)`, the result will be in the same order as they were in the database. I use `random.shuffle()` to solve it.