# How to mix queryset results?

Tags: django

I have query:

```
items = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('nr')[:10]
```

and I get 10 items with higher number. Now I have to mix these results. How to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "mix"? Do you want to shuffle them randomly?

Comment: Yes, I want shuffle this results

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't reorder a query once a slice has been taken, so use different approach

```
import random
items = sorted(MyModel.objects.all().order_by('nr')[:10], key=lambda x: random.random())
```

Answer (score 33):

Curiously, this not very well documented feature works:

```
Country.objects.order_by('?')
```

source: http://www.jpstacey.info/blog/2008/09/03/random-ordering-of-query-results-in-django

> Astonishingly, [the existing documentation](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/ordering/) has very little Google juice, unless you search for "randomly" rather than "random".

Comment: The reason why it's not very well documented is because doing it that way is going to cause huge performance issues on larger databases. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731346/how-to-get-two-random-records-with-django#6405601

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#ordering

Answer (score 19):

OK, you can't re-order a queryset after you've pulled it in, but you can do this instead

```
import random
items = list(MyModel.objects.all().order_by('nr')[:10])
random.shuffle(items)
```

Comment: Would the downvoter like to comment as to why this isn't an appropriate answer, and I'll update it?

Comment: This is a perfectly appropriate answer. Here is my upvote.