# Add an element of randomness to ordering in SQL, django

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, random

I am using Python/Django but I am suspecting that this is going to have to be done on the mysql level.

If I have a model such as:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to query for articles with the highest ratings but I want to add an element of randomness. I don't just want all of them to have ratings of 100 out of 100.

If I was doing this in python I would do something like

```
articles = Article.objects.all()
#multiply each rating by a random multiplier and store that value in a tuple with the article
articles = [(random.random()*article.rating, article) for article in articles] 
#sort by the calculated rating*random value
articles.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0], reverse=True)
```

And maybe that is the best I can do. But if I was going to take this down to the query level, this is about all I have so far:

```
articles = Article.objects.extra(select={"rand_rating":'( rating * {})'.format( random.random() )})
articles = articles.extra(order_by=['rand_rating'])
```

Which at first glance I thought might work, but the random.random() number is just going to be multiplying everything by the same constant which is essentially useless. I looked into the sql RAND() but from what I have read, I will have the same problem as the RAND() isn't called for each row, but rather just once per query.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to mix queryset results?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12073425/1025391)

Answer (score 1):

There is a random ordering built into `.order_by()` using the string `'?'`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by

In your case it would be:

`Article.objects.order_by('?')`

After ordering them, you might then filter out the top X records and again order them by rating.

Comment: This is random but I think the results aren't the same. Randomly ordering the articles then taking the top half, then sorting them by rating would still give me mostly 100/100 ratings. Wheras the probability of getting something that has a 50/100 at the front of the list is greater in my algorithm.

Comment: I think you could chain `.distinct('rating')` to the end of the random ordering. This would make it possible to find only one 100/100 rating (or none at all, if you limit to a subset using `[:10]`, for instance), with the rest being a random set of other rating values. If the set of articles is large enough (say, 1000), it would show a decent spread. -- Granted, you ask in your original question for the highest ratings, which you can use `.filter()` to select.