# How can i avoid repeating objects with endless pagination and order_by('?') queryset

Tags: django, pagination, django-views, django-endless-pagination

I am using django-endless-pagination with its twitter-style pagination. Now i want to paginate over shuffled query set. I have tried to add

```
return Fact.objects.all().order_by('?')
```

But then objects can appear more than 1 time.
How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I think using pagination is misleading in this case. When the user clicks on page 2 it's not actually the second page, it's just another 20 items.

A better option is having a single button (called Fetch for example) and fetch 20 items (or whatever the page size is) each time the user clicks on it.</s>
To avoid the same item showing up twice, you can keep a list of viewed ids in session and exclude them from the subsequent queries.

Comment: I am using twitter-style pagination, it`s 1 page endless pagination and i download new post with ajax, some kind of fetch button.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry didn't catch that.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that you can take try is something that I used and I found on another StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073425/how-to-mix-queryset-results).

```
import random
items = sorted(Fact.objects.all().order_by('nr'), key=lamda x: random.random())
return items
```