# Filter QuerySet with a list of indexes

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a QuerySet like this

```
QS = SomeModel.objects.filter(some_filter='filter_value')
```

I need to randomly pick n elements from this, so I generated a list of n random numbers between 0 to length of QS, into a list variable idx_list.

Now, I can loop through idx_list and pick up one element at a time from QS, but, can I do it without looping, in one line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get two random records with Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731346/how-to-get-two-random-records-with-django)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch items from db and than You can select objects in random order using [`.order_by('?')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) and than generate the id list

You can fetch only the id's in random order using `values_list()`

```
idx_list = SomeModel.objects.filter(some_filter='filter_value').order_by('?').values_list('id', flat=True)[:x]
```

Or you can fetch the queryset:

```
QS = SomeModel.objects.filter(some_filter='filter_value').order_by('?')
```

At then slice as many items as you want:

```
# Get id's of random x elements
idx_list = map(lambda item: item.id, list(QS[0:x]))
```

Comment: Note that this method makes your server crawl into a corner and cry for weeks, filling up ram before it bottlenecks the disk I/O, and not responding to anyone or anything, before it spits out a result that can be achieved in less than a second. Please forget `order_by('?')` ever existed.

Comment: Not everyone has database tables with 100k+ records. Not everyone needs fancy solutions in simple cases.

Comment: Thanks Secator, but I am worried about the performance of '?', because I will need to repeat this filtering for few times on few thousand entries on every user request, and at any time there might be few thousand users. I'm keeping the loop for now: [QS(j) for j in random.sample(range(1, len(QS)), n)], what do you think ?