# Django - Create proposals from many tables

Tags: python, sql, django, optimization

Have a look at the following code snippet:

```
def post_proposals(count):
    post_elements = chain(
            PostModel1.objects.all(),
            PostModel2.objects.all(),
            PostModel3.objects.all(),
        )
    post_elements_list = list(post_elements)
    post_proposals = random.sample(post_elements_list, count)
    return post_proposals
```

Where it's requiered to generate a list of proposals from 3 different Post tables, how to optimize a disgn flaw like this?
Already came accorss the idea to build a Index table where all PKs of all my PostModel{1..3} are stored, so that I just have to query 1 table instead of three.
Does smb. have a practical idea on how to solve this or at least optimizing it?

Comment: one possible solution is that you can decompose `count` into three small integers,  then randomly get these number of rows accordingly using `Model.objects.order_by('?')[:n]` as  mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731346/how-to-get-two-random-records-with-django

Comment: Thanks for that comment, will have a look at it :D