# Custom filter for Django querysets

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

Good day, I have a problem: I have a model with some fields.

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='gallery/')
    status = models.BooleanField()
    type = models.BooleanField()
```

I used this model for storing gallery image in masonry grid. This grid is fixed and I need to get 12 random image, this is easy to do.

```
gallery = Gallery.objects.all().order_by('id','pk').order_by('?')[: 12];
```

But 5 of them should have True type, and 7 others - False. And I'll be insanely happy if it'll be able to custom an order in this queryset, for example, True means horizontal picture(h), False - vertical[v]. I want to get an order like this [v,h,h,h,v,v,v,h,h,v,v,v]

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you need; but what about `first getting 5 random True type, then getting 7 random False type and combine these two query results`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do two queries, one for horizontal and one for vertical objects.

```
horizontal = Gallery.objects.filter(type=True).order_by('?')[:7]
vertical = Gallery.objects.filter(type=False).order_by('?')[:5]
```

Then construct the list from your two querysets

```
gallery = [verical[0]] + horizontal[0:3] + vertical[1:4] + horizontal[3:] + vertical[4:]
```

Note that the [order_by docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) warn that `order_by('?')` may be slow. If you hit performance problems, you might want to look for an alternative approach. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962619/how-to-pull-a-random-record-using-djangos-orm) for example.