# Django distribute filter results

Tags: python, django, filter, orm

In a Django app, I am doing query like below:

```
Products.objects.filter(category_id=[1, 2, 3])[:6]
```

I am getting back 6 items from category 1. What I want is form each category 2 items.

Alternatively I tried with `Q` like below:

```
Products.objects.filter(Q(category_id=1)|Q(category_id=2)|Q(category_id=3))[:6]
```

I can get all the results and then iterate through the results to filter out and so on. The resulted query set is pretty large.

How can I make that query using Django ORM via single query without iterating through the whole queryset?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any direct way to do that. Some workarounds I can think of:

### Direct iteration (1 query) :

The most direct way, only involve one query. Remember to use [iterator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) so you don't have the full queryset in memory.

```
for product in Products.objects.filter(category_id__in=[1, 2, 3]).iterator():
    # Add some logic to select your six items.
```

Of course depending on the iteration order it could be time consuming (for instance if all your category 1 items were inserted first). Throwing a random order [`.order('?')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962619/how-to-pull-a-random-record-using-djangos-orm) may help but be careful that it have some caveats (mainly, it's slow).

### Query each category (as many queries as categories):

```
[
    p
    for category_id in [1, 2, 3]
    for p in Products.objects.filter(category_id=category_id)[:2]
]
```

The result is not a queryset anymore, but that may not matter.

### Multiple rounds (2 queries if you want the first 2 of each):

Get the first of each categories, exclude them and then get the second ones.

```
ids = [1, 2, 3]
items = list(Products.objects.filter(category_id__in=ids).distinct('category'))

items += list(Products.objects.filter(category_id__in=ids).exclude(
    id__in=[i.id for i in items],
).distinct('category'))
```

Same caveat that it's a list and not a queryset anymore and also see the limitations on [`distinct(*field)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `category_id__in=[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: @user3764893 No, on method 2 we are querying the categories individually.

Comment: I mean in your direct iteration `for product in Products.objects.filter(category_id=[1, 2, 3]).iterator():`