# How to randomise the order of a queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Consider the following query:

`candidates = Candidate.objects.filter(ElectionID=ElectionIDx)`

Objects in this query are ordered by their `id` field.

How do I randomise the order of the objects in the query? Can it be done using `.order_by()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull a random record using Django's ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962619/how-to-pull-a-random-record-using-djangos-orm)

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Thank you, that link is very useful. Question is slightly different but the information is 100% relevant and helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the special argument `?` with `order_by` to get randomized queryset:

```
Candidate.objects.filter(ElectionID=ElectionIDx).order_by('?')
```

[Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

Note that, depending on the DB backend, the randomization might be slow and expensive. I would suggest you to do the benchmark first. If you feel it's slow, then try finding alternatives, before that go with `?` first.

Comment: Note that according to the documentation these "queries may be expensive and slow, depending on the database backend you’re using."

Comment: @BUZZY is there a less expensive way of achieving the same outcome?

Comment: @cbuch1800 Do the benchmark first. If you feel it's slow, then try finding alternatives, before that go with `?` first.