# django models output ordering of banners

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django site that i'm managing for a client of mine that is around 5 years old. It has a very simple carousel on one of the pages that is content managed. THe client wants these images to be randomly picked on page load as opposed to the order in which they are organised in the CMS. Here is the code for the models for this element

```
 from django.db import models

 class Banner(models.Model):

 created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 active = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Display this banner on the website.')

 title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 description = models.TextField()
 image = models.ImageField(upload_to='banners/')
 order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

 class Meta:
    ordering = ['order']
```

I was wondering if someone could help me by showing me how to do this or if it's even possible? This, in my opinion, is different from the suggested link as it does not show how to address this problem specifically.

Comment: What is the result of this code? Are the banners ordered by `order` field? It looks ok for me tbh.

Comment: Yes they are ordered by the order field but i want them to randomly organised

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull a random record using Django's ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962619/how-to-pull-a-random-record-using-djangos-orm)

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle your query set by using

```
banner_obj = Banner.objects.all().order_by('?')
```

which will give you random result on every call

Comment: OK thank you, please could you advise how and where this would be integrated into the code?

Comment: I haven't added it to the code above yet as I'm not sure how to integrate your suggestion into it

Comment: could you possibly elaborate on this for me?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to randomise things with js in the end as I didn't have time to work through an option with regards to the original query