# How do I order my objects in a random way?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm using Django with Python 3.7 and PostGres 9.5.  I use the following to get all my objects and iterate over them ...

```
article_set = Article.objects.all()
for article in article_set:
```

Is there a way to modify my existing query or possibly the loop so that the objects are returned in a random order each time?  I would prefer not to make a second query if at all possible.

Comment: Instead of asking on StackOverflow before doing any work, it's generally a good idea to google your question - `random.shuffle()` is hard to miss.

Comment: maybe duplicate question?, check this link : [How to pull a random record using Django's ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962619/how-to-pull-a-random-record-using-djangos-orm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull a random record using Django's ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962619/how-to-pull-a-random-record-using-djangos-orm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As is explained in the documentation you can use `order_by('?')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) as follows:

```
article_set = Article.objects.order_by('?')
```

Comment: Note that `order_by('?')` queries may be expensive and slow. Try to avoid this if possible in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Django, and correct me if I'm wrong but I'd assume that:

```
Article.objects.all()
#Roughly equates to:
"SELECT * from articles"
```

So I believe you should be able to do:

```
Article.objects.all().order_by('RANDOM()')
#Thus producing this SQL statement:
"SELECT * from articles ORDER BY RANDOM()"
```

Which should mix up your output.

---

Otherwise, I'd say go with the `random.shuffle` approach.

```
from random import shuffle

article_set = Article.objects.all()
for article in shuffle(article_set):
    #do work
```

Let me know if the order_by worked and I can edit accordingly. Like I said I'm not too familiar with Django so this is untested but in theory should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make a loop like this

```
article_set = Article.objects.all()
for article in random.shuffle(article_set):
    print(article)
```