# How to random model in django?

Tags: python, django

User on main.html can choose category from select and get the question.
App list **all** filtered questions by category.
How to random questions and show the only one question?

I see, the all questions are `qs` in `ShowFilterView`, but how take `questions` and randomize them?

**views.py**:

```
def is_valid_queryparam(param):
    return param != '' and param is not None

def filter(request):
    qs = Cards.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    category = request.GET.get('category')

    if is_valid_queryparam(category):
        qs = qs.filter(categories__name=category)

    return qs

def MakeFilterView(request):
    qs = filter(request)
    context = {
        'queryset': qs,
        'categories': Category.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, "cards/main.html", context)

def ShowFilterView(request):
    qs = filter(request)
    context = {
        'queryset': qs,
        'categories': Category.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, "cards/result.html", context)
```

**models.py**:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Вопрос', max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Категория', max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Cards(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.question)
```

**result.html**:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
        {% for cards in queryset %}
          {{ cards.question.name }}<br/>
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You want to pick a random question from the database?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962619/how-to-pull-a-random-record-using-djangos-orm#  here

Comment: @Phanti. Yes, from database.

Comment: @Sheraram_Prajapat how it render in template?